# NHibernate not deleting child object

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I can't get NHibernate to delete this child object, it completes without throwing any exceptions and without deleting anything:

```
    public void DeleteW9(int vendorId, int vendorW9Id)
    {
        var vendor = vendorRepository.Get(vendorId);
        var W9 = vendor.W9.Where(x => x.Id == vendorW9Id).First();
        vendor.W9.Remove(W9);
        vendorRepository.SaveOrUpdate(vendor);
    }
```

Here's my Vendor mapping:

```
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.W9)
               .KeyColumn("VendorFk")
               .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
               .AsBag();
```

My VendorW9 table contains a reference to the Vendor's ID in the form of the VendorFk. I have no restraints setup, do I need to setup a primary key relationship? NHibernate functions fine for everything but deleting orphans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding vendorRepository.Commit():

```
public void DeleteW9(int vendorId, int vendorW9Id) 
{ 
    var vendor = vendorRepository.Get(vendorId); 
    var W9 = vendor.W9.Where(x => x.Id == vendorW9Id).First(); 
    vendor.W9.Remove(W9); 
    vendorRepository.SaveOrUpdate(vendor);
    vendorRepository.Commit();
}
```

Comment: It seems NHibernate needs to be explicitly told to commit the changes in order to remove orphans.